# Read Comma Delimited Text File

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to read a text file using access vba and looking to return values between quotes.

Example Text File (adm_settings.txt)

```
email_subject| "This is my email subject"
email_body| "This is my email body. 

so many thing 

to 

write"
```

I need to call the function below and return everything between the quotes for the setting requested.

```
Public Function getAdmSettingBAK(sSetting As String) As String

    Dim bFoundIt As Boolean
    Dim sDir As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sLineString As String
    Dim sField() As String

    sDir = CurrentProject.Path & "\"
    sFile = "adm_settings.txt"

    If (Dir(sDir & sFile) = "") Then
        MsgBox "can't find settings file: " & sDir & sFile
        Exit Function
    Else
        'Debug.Print "using settings file: " & sDir; sFile
    End If


    Open sDir & sFile For Input As #1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sLineString
        'Debug.Print sLineString
        sField = Split(sLineString, "|")

        'Debug.Print "setting: " & sField(0) & " == value: " & sField(1)
        If sField(0) = sSetting Then
            bFoundIt = True
            getAdmSetting = sField(1)
        End If

    Loop

    Close #1

    If Not bFoundIt Then
        MsgBox "can't find setting " & sSetting
    End If

 MsgBox "This is the string: " & getAdmSetting
ExitMe:

End Function
```

the function works if I remove the quotes, but will only return the first line (does not include line breaks, etc.

Comment: If no line breaks, try replacing of `getAdmSetting = sField(1)` with `getAdmSetting = sField(1) & VbCrlf`

Comment: Is there a way to get everything between the quotes?  I added the quotes to the text file but it only returns the very first line

Comment: Is efficiency of critical importance? This task is generally a lot easier if you load the entire string in memory, instead of reading it line-by-line. Also, you make several strong assumptions here, creating a proper solution, one that doesn't trigger if the text `email_body| blabla` occurs after a new line in your email title, for example, will create some additional work. Honestly, you're best off using a well-defined format with a pre-made parser if you're not a very experienced programmer.

Comment: Efficiency is not that critical.  Can you suggest a pre-made parser?

Comment: One example for a CSV parser would be https://github.com/sdkn104/VBA-CSV. You'd just have to swap the comma for a pipe since you're using a PSV. I'm not affiliated, and I personally use JSON for config files so I have no experience with that package, but at a glance it looks fine.

Comment: I think you cannot remove the quotation marks because your code wold not know where is the end of your record. Is the 2nd line part of the first record or is it already 2nd record? The "new line" character is not in this case record delimiter but also a new line. If you have not the option to add a record delimiter, you need to code it a little bit more complex and see if the read line includes your pipe "|". If it does not it it means the data belongs to the previous record. If it does it means it is a new record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the other option how you can do it (I tested it with your data):

```vb
Public Function getAdmSettingBAK(sSetting As String) As String
    Dim fso, MyFile
    Dim iStart As Integer, iEnd As Integer
    Dim response As String, myRecord As String
    Dim sField() As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(CurrentProject.path & "\adm_settings.txt", 1)
    response = MyFile.ReadAll

    iStart = InStr(response, sSetting) ' find the sSetting string
    If iStart = 0 Then Exit Function  ' sSetting does not exists
    myRecord = Mid(response, iStart) ' cut off string from start to sSetting

    iStart = InStr(myRecord, "|") ' find the 1st pipe
    iEnd = InStr(Mid(myRecord, iStart + 1), "|")  ' find the 2nd pipe

    If iEnd = 0 Then iEnd = Len(myRecord)  ' there is no more records in file

    myRecord = Mid(myRecord, 1, iStart + iEnd - 1)  ' cutt off up to the end of the 2nd record
    iEnd = InStrRev(myRecord, vbCrLf)  ' find the last new line character
    If iEnd > 0 Then  ' this is not the last record in file
        myRecord = Mid(myRecord, 1, iEnd - 1) ' get the whole record
    End If

    sField = Split(myRecord, "|")
    getAdmSettingBAK= Trim(sField(1))

End Function
```